# Apps Script use Google OAuth to access .net application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-apps-script, oauth-2.0

I have a custom `.net` application that allows `OAuth` login with my Google account.

I would like to leverage some of the API's in `Google Apps Script (GAS)` function, but am not sure if I need to change something in the custom application to allow the `GAS` function to authenticate.

Is this possible? If so, how? Or, what should I be searching to find a possible solution? Is it already enabled because `OAuth` is enabled within the application?

When I tried `UrlFetchApp.fetch` it returned the login page, so obviously the API call from the function is unable to access the cookies on my machine and I am not sure how to pass the credentials to the API via `GAS`.

Answer (score 0):

There's actually a [.NET Quickstart for Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/quickstart/dotnet) which includes Auth. This is the closest thing I can find from the docs where .NET and Apps Script work together.

Here's the Auth part

UserCredential credential;

```
        using (var stream =
            new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
                System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/script-dotnet-quickstart.json");

            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                Scopes,
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
            Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
        }
```